# Android studio import locally a GitHub lib

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I can't find out how to import locally a lib.

I'm importing this lib : https://github.com/Senth/MaterialShowcaseView

with jitpack.

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

but i want to clone it to modify the lib and then import it but i just can't find out how to import it once modified

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a repository like a github repository and then a way to import, like uploading your repository to maven central.  Here is a way to do it. [Import a Repository](https://www.wikihow.com/Import-a-Repository-on-Github)